# Testing custom validators with rspec. Why do I get Proc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

As the title suggest I am trying to test a custom validator with Rspec. I get an error and I don't understand why... If you can shed some light I would really appreciate it. Here we go:

**Validator spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GraphDateValidator do

  it "should not validate activity with empty start time" do
    expect { Graph.new( {start_time: ''}).valid? }.to eq(false)
  end
end
```

If I print `Graph.new( {start_time: ''}).valid?` it prints `false`

However when it goes through the spec it returns a Proc object:

```
expected: false
            got: #<Proc:0x007fe5853fdd48@/Users/MLP/...
```

Can anybody tell me why I am getting that proc object? Thank you!

Comment: is the use of squirely brackets "{}" a typo? normally, it's expect().to eq(false)

Comment: I just notice that :) I really couldn't see it :) Thanks. If you put down the answer I can accept it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using {} in your expect, then you really aren't executing the expect method --- instead you're sending expect a block. So rename to

```
it "should not validate activity with empty start time" do
  expect( Graph.new( {start_time: ''}).valid? ).to eq(false)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

For better style and fail messages, you can use rspec's predicate matchers:

```
it "does not accept empty start time" do
  Graph.new( {start_time: ''}).should_not be_valid
end
```

Edit 1 (explain style tastes):

This gives you readable error messages like "expected $foo to be valid, but wasn't" instead of "true should be false".

With "better style" I was referencing the use of a Matcher (as I wrote), not the `should`. So the following would not use deprecated syntax, but still use matchers:

```
it "does not accept empty start time" do
  expect( Graph.new( {start_time: ''}) ).to be_valid
end
```

Comment: this way is deprecated so im skeptical this is "better style"

Comment: at least it gives you readable error messages like "expected $foo to be valid, but wasn't" instead of "true should be false".

"better style" was referencing the use of a matcher, not the `should`. So the follwing would not use deprecated syntax, but still use matchers:


    it "does not accept empty start time" do
      expect( Graph.new( {start_time: ''}) ).to be_valid
    end